# When I overwrite the response body in my middleware, why is the response body not being resized?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a middleware that replaces a string in my html page.
The replaced value is shorter then the string to replace. So my response is shorter then the original response.
My outputted html ends up with part of the original response.

My html ends with

```
</body>
</html>
body>
</html>
```

the last

```
body></html>
```

being the length of the difference in length between the new and old response body.

This is my middleware

```
public class AuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private string _employeeid = "test";
    private readonly string SCRIPT = "";
    private readonly string EMPLOYEENUMB_SCRIPT_PLACEHOLDER = "[[EMPLOYEENUMB]]";
    private HttpRequest _request;
    private HttpResponse _response;
    private HttpContext _context;

    public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        _context = httpContext;
        _request = _context.Request;
        _request.EnableBuffering();

        await SetEmployeeIdInResponse();
    }

    private async Task SetEmployeeIdInResponse()
    {
        _response = _context.Response;

        using (var resMS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var originalResponseBodyReference = _response.Body;
            _response.Body = resMS;

            await _next(_context);

            // set to begining to be able to read
            _response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // get the response body content
            var responseBody = await new StreamReader(_response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            // update body content
            var newResponseBody = responseBody.Replace(EMPLOYEENUMB_SCRIPT_PLACEHOLDER, _employeeid);

            // set to begining to be able to write                
            _response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // write the new content to the response body, which is the new MemoryStream
            await _response.WriteAsync(newResponseBody);

            // set to begining to be able to write                
            _response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                

            // copy the new MemoryStream (new content) to the original response/MemoryStream
            await resMS.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBodyReference);             
        }
    }
}
```

newResponseBody only contains what I need.
Why is the Response Body not the same as newResponseBody ?

Comment: Is this custom middleware used to change a specific value in the view?  If so , why don't you just achieve it in client side? It will more easier to achieve it. We are not very recommended you to do it in your way, it will affect something else.

Comment: Because I need to inject a value in the client script before the client can make calls to the API